# TypeScript does not detect generic class

Tags: typescript, generics

I have such simple class where I am trying to constrain the type of the object inside my class using generic type (Dog in this case). I expect to see the compilation error here box.put(cat) because I pass the wrong type but unfortunately, I don`t see any.

```
class Box<T>{
    content: Array<T> = [];

    put(animal: T){
        this.content.push(animal);
    }
}

var dog = new Dog();
var cat = new Cat();

var box = new Box<Dog>();
box.put(cat);
```

Answer (score 4):

Typescript uses structural compatibility to determine type compatibility. So given your code, if `Dog` and `Cat` have these definitions

```
class Dog{ name: string }
class Cat{ name: string; lives: number }
```

Your code will work because `Cat` has all the fields of `Dog` and is thus compatible.

If you defined the classes like this:

```
class Dog{ name: string; isAsGoodBoy: boolean }
class Cat{ name: string; lives: number }
```

Your code will no longer work, because `Dog` has fields `Cat` does not.

A useful way to think about it if you are familiar with Javascript is that structural typing is the compile time version of duck typing.

Comment: @zdimon77 Glad to help, don't forget to mark as answered :)